# Strong params when POSTing multiple items to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am trying to create multiple records via a POST request to the Rails API but am having issues with the params side of things.

What is happening is the item is not being created as the callbacks in the model are looking for values that are not present. I believe this has something to do with the params.

Here is my code:

```
  def batch_create
    params[:product].each do |p|
      product = Product.new(batch_create_product_params)
      product.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  def batch_create_product_params
    params.permit(:name, :link, :category_old, :image_url, :price, :interest, :revenue, :end_date, :company, :country, :above_average_revenue)
  end
```

The raw contents of my json call are:

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "name": "Strap On SoftRack Roof Rack by Otium Acupressure",
            "link": "https://things.com/89902997836713867011111211111121/Strap-On-SoftRack-Roof-Rack-by-Otium",
            "category_old": "",
            "image_url": "https://thingd-media-ec1.com/default/899029978367138670_42120cf10765.jpg",
            "price": "160",
            "interest": "9999",
            "company": "ACME",
            "country": "USA",
            "revenue": "999999"
        },
        {
            "name": "Strap On SoftRack Roof Rack by Otium Acupressure 2",
            "link": "https://things.com/Strap-On-SoftRack-Roof-Rack-by-Otium",
            "category_old": "",
            "image_url": "https://thingd-media-ec1.com/default/899029978367138670_42120cf10765.jpg",
            "price": "160",
            "interest": "9999",
            "company": "ACME",
            "country": "USA",
            "revenue": "999999"
        }
    ]
}
```

The resulting params are then as follows:

The total parameters when the call is first made.

```
Parameters: {"product"=>[{"name"=>"Strap On SoftRack Roof Rack by Otium Acupressure", "link"=>"https://fancy.com/things/89902997836713867011111211111121/Strap-On-SoftRack-Roof-Rack-by-Otium", "category_
old"=>"", "image_url"=>"https://thingd-media-ec1.thefancy.com/default/899029978367138670_42120cf10765.jpg", "price"=>"160", "interest"=>"9999", "company"=>"Fancy", "country"=>"USA", "revenue"=>"999999"},
{"name"=>"Strap On SoftRack Roof Rack by Otium Acupressure 2", "link"=>"https://fancy.com/things/Strap-On-SoftRack-Roof-Rack-by-Otium", "category_old"=>"", "image_url"=>"https://thingd-media-ec1.thefancy.
com/default/899029978367138670_42120cf10765.jpg", "price"=>"160", "interest"=>"9999", "company"=>"Fancy", "country"=>"USA", "revenue"=>"999999"}], "import"=>{}}
```

The params once they are in the loop.

```
{"name"=>"Strap On SoftRack Roof Rack by Otium Acupressure", "link"=>"https://fancy.com/things/89902997836713867011111211111121/Strap-On-SoftRack-Roof-Rack-by-Otium", "category_old"=>"", "i
mage_url"=>"https://thingd-media-ec1.thefancy.com/default/899029978367138670_42120cf10765.jpg", "price"=>"160", "interest"=>"9999", "company"=>"Fancy", "country"=>"USA", "revenue"=>"999999"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is more like this.  Placing the root `product` key in the permit call tells rails that this is going to be an array of objects, containing the keys noted.

```
def batch_create
  batch_create_product_params[:product].each do |product_params|
    product = Product.new(product_params)
    product.save
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @product }
  end
end

def batch_create_product_params
  params.permit(product: [:name, :link, :category_old, :image_url, :price, :interest, :revenue, :end_date, :company, :country, :above_average_revenue])
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked a charm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `new` takes an array.  I think you would need to do this - use the `p` param in the strong parameters.

```
  def batch_create
    params[:product].each do |p|
      product = Product.new(batch_create_product_params(p)) # Pass p
      product.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  def batch_create_product_params(p) # Accept params
    p.permit(:name, :link, :category_old, :image_url, :price, :interest, :revenue, :end_date, :company, :country, :above_average_revenue)
  end
```

`create` does take an array.  Maybe this would do in your case.

```
def batch_create
  product = Product.create(batch_create_product_params[:product])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @product }
  end
end

def batch_create_product_params
  params.permit(product: [:name, :link, :category_old, :image_url, :price, :interest, :revenue, :end_date, :company, :country, :above_average_revenue])
end
```